# How to remove a character from a string within a list PYTHON

Tags: python, list

I currently have the following code but I am struggling to figure out the code that will remove the punctuation from the strings within the list. Please let me know if you know what I should input.

```
"""
This function checks to see if the last character is either punctuation or a
"\n" character and removes these unwanted characters.

Question: 1
"""

import string
result = string.punctuation

def myFun(listA):
    A = listA
    for element in A:
        for i in element:
            if i in result:
                #what do i put here
        print(A)
myFun(['str&', 'cat', 'dog\n', 'myStr.'])
```

Comment: The code doesn't look properly formatted, to fix it, press the edit option, and then you can select the text that is your code, and press ctrl-k.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, string is basically a list of characters, so you can access the last character by `str[-1]`, or if you wanna check for `\n`, `str[-2:]`

Now, you can perform a simple check on `str[-1]` first by,

`if str[-1] in string.punctuation`

and remove it with `str = str[:-1]`

and `str[-2:]` by:

`if str[-2:] == "\n"`

and remove it with `str = str[:-2]`

Notes: After you perform each checking, remember to add a `continue` to iterate to the next loop, or else, it will remove from the `str` twice for case that ends with both `\n` and a punctuation, such as "test\n," will become "test"

p.s. I intentionally didn't put them in your code and left that part for you to do.

Comment: Thanks! Got it sorted. I definitely thought I was making it too complicated.